# Error while accessing members of UIColor extension

Tags: swift, uicolor, swift-extensions

I want to move custom colors to an extension of UIColor:

```
extension UIColor {
    static var nonSelectedTabColor: UIColor {
        return UIColor(white: 0.682, alpha: 1) // #AEAEAE
    }
}
```

But on trying to access it, its causing me an error:

```
private static let defaultBorderColor = .nonSelectedTabColor
```

`Reference to member 'nonSelectedTabColor' cannot be resolved without a contextual type`.

What is the issue here? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler cannot know that you are referring to a member of
`UIColor`. Either

```
private static let defaultBorderColor = UIColor.nonSelectedTabColor
```

or

```
private static let defaultBorderColor: UIColor = .nonSelectedTabColor
```

would solve the issue. In the second line, the type `UIColor`
is inferred from the context, and `.nonSelectedTabColor`
is an “implicit member expression.”